# Print data from db.currentOp to webpage

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Codeigniter (Cimongo) and I need to print out the results from
the command db.currentOp on a webpage so that I can use the data to debug.

How can I do this?

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Viewing and Terminating Current Operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation) from the MongoDB docs, the `db.currentOp()` command is simply a query against the special `$cmd.sys.inprog` collection of a database. You can also confirm this via the JS shell:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.0
connecting to: test
> db.currentOp
function (arg) {
    var q = {};
    if (arg) {
        if (typeof arg == "object") {
            Object.extend(q, arg);
        } else if (arg) {
            q.$all = true;
        }
    }
    return this.$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne(q);
}
```

I haven't worked with CodeIgniter or Cimongo, but looking at [Cimongo.php](https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/master/libraries/cimongo/Cimongo.php), you should be able to use the `get()` method with `$cmd.sys.inprog` to receive a cursor, which you can then use to read the first element. There doesn't appear to be any abstraction for `MongoCollection::findOne()`, but that would have been my first choice for doing this in raw PHP:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$inprog = $mongo->selectCollection('test', '$cmd.sys.inprog');
var_dump($inprog->findOne());
```